# how to add a new page for a long Table in itextSharp

Tags: c#, datatable, itext

my problem is that itext doesn't add new page for long Tables,it just render one page and only a part of the table is shown, here is my code :

```
MemoryStream reportStream = new MemoryStream();
IEnumerable<Site> siteList = SiteManager.GetAllSites();
Document doc = new Document();
doc.SetMargins(7f, 10f, 10f, 7f);
var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, reportStream);
writer.CloseStream = false;
doc.Open();
PdfPTable tableLayout = new PdfPTable(11);
var personalTable = AddPersonalTable(tableLayout);
personalTable.WriteSelectedRows(0, -1, 0, 842, doc.Left, doc.Top 
,writer.DirectContent);
doc.Close();
byte[] byteInfo = reportStream.ToArray();
reportStream.Write(byteInfo, 0, byteInfo.Length);
reportStream.Position = 0;
return reportStream;
```

and my method:

```
private static PdfPTable AddPersonalTable(PdfPTable tableLayout)
{
        float[] headers = { 12, 9, 10, 4, 9, 11, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9 };  
        tableLayout.SetWidths(headers);       
        tableLayout.WidthPercentage = 100;      
        tableLayout.HeaderRows = 1;
        //adding cells
        return tableLayout;
}
```

I appreciate any help.

Comment: I don't see you adding anything to the document at all...

Comment: it's in the //add cells comments, it's just a simple tableLayout.AddCell(...)

Comment: So you add content to the table, ok, but you don't add the table to the document. Most likely, though, the error is in your code adding the table to the document.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add it in my question, whatever my problem was solved, I changed the `WriteSelectedRows` by `doc.Add(personalTable)`, thank you so much for your interest in my problem